# pip install is giving weird errors on a RPI 3B+ with rasbian

Tags: python, pip

If I try to install something using pip it gives me a weird error. Time is set correctly and sudo doesn't change anything. For example I try installing conan `pip install conan​` gives an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install conan
​Invalid requirement: 'conan​'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 253, in from_line
  req = Requirement(req)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 97, in __init__
requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'\xe2\x80\x8b'"
```

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Have you updated anything recently? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625488/invalidrequirement-invalid-requirement-parse-error-error-after-updating-a-py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the same error today, it can be resolved by typing in:

```
sudo pip install --no-cache-dir conan
```

If you run it with the `-v` (verbose) you can see it errors at some point in the cache.

Comment: If possible, please talk a little bit about why this would resolve the problem stated in the question

Comment: I would if I knew more about why it worked. All I know is I saw cache errors in verbose mode and by running it without using the cache dir it worked.